# for loop to be used with readpst library

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am having an issue with for loop on centos:

I am trying to convert a lot of .pst files using readpst library:

the following works fine:

```
/bin/readpst -o /destination_directory -M -S -e -D /source_location/sample.pst
```

however when I try to run:

```
for i in 'cat list_all_psts.txt'; do /bin/readpst -M -S -e -D /source_location/sample.pst -o /destination_directory; done
```

I get error opening File.

so I tried to add "sleep 30":

```
for i in 'cat list_all_psts.txt'; do /bin/readpst -M -S -e -D /source_location/sample.pst -o /destination_directory; sleep 30; done
```

with no avail. 
Does anyone have an idea what is wrong with this syntax? 
Any help would be much appreciated

Regards, 
R

Comment: try while loop  like  `while read line;do  echo $line ;done  < list_all_psts.txt`

Comment: also wondering where have you used `i` inside for loop

Comment: Hi - thank you for your comment.
I did add $i instead of /source_location/sampe.pst 

so you suggest to use the while loop instead?

Comment: Hi there, 

Many many thanks for help!!! :) - you saved me a lot of time. 
'while read line; do /bin/readpst -M -S -e -D /source_location/$line -o /destination_directory ;done < list_all_psts.txt' 

have a good day/evening/night